# bash, break loop if input value is contained in array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I want to check if the user input value exists in the array, then stop checking inputs. I tried

```
var=( one two three )
while true; do
  read -p "Choose value:   " val
  for i in "${var[@]}";do
    [ "$i" = "$val" ] && exit 0;
  done
done

echo SUCCESS
```

With that the script will exit, but I want the script to continue and print SUCCESS.

I tried the break instruction but the while loop just continues and does not break.

Comment: Replace `exit 0` by `break 2` (that is, break two loop levels). Note that, if your bash supports it, an associative array (where the keys are the values of your indexed array) would simplify a bit and require only one loop level: `[[ -v var["$val"] ]] && break`.

Comment: I was typing in my answer while this comment happened. No problem, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a level with your break statement like so:

```
var=( one two three )
while true; do
  read -p "Choose value:   " val
  for i in "${var[@]}";do
    [ "$i" = "$val" ] && break 2;
  done
done
echo SUCCESS
```

It will break the outer loop (while at level 2).

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the nested loops, requires an *associative* array approach from `@Renaud Pacalet`, an alternative is to format the array and use the `[[...]]`  instead of `[...]`, something like:

- With an *extglob* feature:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var=( one two three )
pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '@(%s)' "${var[*]}")

while read -rp "Choose value:  " val; do
  [[ "$val" = $pattern ]] && {
    printf "SUCCESS\n" && break
  }
done
```

- From `bashv 4.1` the `extglob` feature/support from `[[ ... ]]` is on by default, any lower version requires `shopt -s extglob` to enable it.

---

- With a regex using the `=~` operator:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

var=( one two three )
pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "${var[*]}")

while read -rp "Choose value:   " val; do
  [[ "$val" =~ $pattern ]] && {
    printf "SUCCESS\n" && break
  }
done
```

---

- The right hand side of the test does not need to be quoted, otherwise it will be treated as a literal and not a glob or regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `exit 0` by `break 2` (that is, break two loop levels). Another option is to print your success message and exit:

```
var=( one two three )
while true; do
  read -p "Choose value:   " val
  for i in "${var[@]}";do
    [ "$i" = "$val" ] && echo "SUCCESS" && exit 0;
  done
done
```

Finally, if your bash supports it, an associative array with your values as keys would simplify a bit and require only one loop level:

```
declare -A var=( ["one"]= ["two"]= ["three"]= )
while true; do
  read -p "Choose value:   " val
  [[ -v var["$val"] ]] && break
done

echo "SUCCESS"
```